# Copying File lists from Explorer (Windows XP) to MS Word document

Tags: windows-explorer

I have a long list of research papers listed as files in Explorer.  Is there a less tedious way of listing these in a Word document than opening each one and using copy/paste?

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt and run

```
dir /b
```

This will create a list of all the files in the current folder. If the list is to long to copy and paste you can redirect the output of the command to a file and open it afterwards.

```
dir /b > filelisting.txt
```